# Android FileProvider not able to view image using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-download-manager, android-fileprovider

**Share Image Using URL**

**FragmentDeatails.kt**

```
buttonShare.setOnClickListener {
                shareImage()
            }
```

```
fun shareImage(){
 val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/images/" + "test.jpg")

        Log.d("Test", "${file.absolutePath}")

        val uriFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(),
            "dev.iamspathan.imageify.fileprovider",
            file)
        val mimetype = "image/jpeg"
        val myIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        myIntent.setDataAndType(uriFile, mimetype)
        val intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Choose Application")
        startActivity(intentChooser)

}
```

**file_path.xml**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <external-path name="external" path="."/>

    <root-path
        name="external"
        path="/storage/" />

    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />

    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />

</paths>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="dev.iamspathan.imageify.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_path" />
        </provider>
```

When i'm clicking on button to send image using intent. It's empty.

I tried to debug file provider uri.
Which is: **content://{mypackagename}.fileprovider/external/images/test.jpg**

Help me resolve this:(

Comment: Use `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` on both `Intent` objects, or switch to `ShareCompat`. See https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/01/07/action_send-share-sheet-clipdata.html for more.